# DIV with width:100% is just 100% of the viewport

Tags: css, wordpress, scroll, width, viewport

Maybe the title is not easy to understand, sorry.

My problem in detail: i created a wordpress theme with an header. This header is surrounded by the "header-div". The header div has a width: 100% and a coloured background. But if the content in another div below overflows the viewport and you scroll horizontal, the background is white.

I know that the "width:100%" just is 100% of the parent element, but there is just the body. And the body has "width:100% and height:100%".

Where is the mistake?

Here is the site:

http://ericgerhardy.de/selltron/

Just try to reduce the browser width to 500px and scroll to the right. This should show my problem.

PS. I´m sorry if the question is already answered, but i searched for a while, with no results.

Answer (score 1):

The white background appears because you have set a min-width: 1000px at some of the elements below the header.

If your only concern is to prevent the white background from appearing at the right side of the header on smaller screens and you don't care about having a responsive page (which is the case, if I understood your question), then you need to add **min-width: 1000px;** to your **#header** as well like this:

```
#header {
    background-color: #D3D0CE;
    height: 245px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99999;
    min-width: 1000px; /* This is the extra line */
}
```

Comment: At first- thank you! I tried it an it works! I thought I already tried it, but I think I was wrong. At the moment this solution is perfect, but for the future I try to it the responsive way.

Comment: If you want to make it responsive I suggest that you start now. Otherwise it will be hard to convert a non-responsive site to a responsive one. For starters you need to remove all "min-width:1000px" from your css and use percentages (%) instead of pixels to set the width of your elements.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that absolute positioned elements doesn't resize their parents but overflows them.

In this case your body is overflowed and a scrollbar appears but his size is still 100% of the viewport, because he is not expanded.

The abuse of absolute positiong often leads to such problems. Try tu use static positioning as much as possible. In this case it's really  easy to use static positioning.